# Executing GitHub CLI command in Process class returns exitValue = 1 instead of JSON [Java SpringBoot]

Tags: java, json, spring, github, command-line-interface

I want to execute a GitHub CLI command using the Process class in Java:

`gh api /users/abcslawek/repos --jq 'map(select(.fork == false))|.[]|{Repository_name: .name, Owner_login: .owner.login}'`

This command in PowerShell returns JSON:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DidaF.png)
but after entering `http://localhost:8080/repo` in browser my Intellij console shows `ERROR - exitValue() = 1` and there is empty JSON in my browser.
Here is my whole code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrRbH.png)

I would like to see the same JSON in browser as in PowerShell.

**Application.java:**

```
package com.slaweklida.githubDataScrapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller.java:**

```
package com.slaweklida.githubDataScrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ProfileService profileService;

    @GetMapping("/repo")
    public List<ProfileRepository> getProfileRepositories() {
        try {
            return profileService.executeConsoleCommand("gh api /users/abcslawek/repos --jq 'map(select(.fork == false))|.[]|{Repository_name: .name, Owner_login: .owner.login}'");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return List.of();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProfileService.java:**

```
package com.slaweklida.githubDataScrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
@Service
public class ProfileService {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ProfileService() {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    public List<ProfileRepository> executeConsoleCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();

        if(process.exitValue() != 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - exitValue() = " + process.exitValue());
            return List.of();
        }

        return objectMapper.readValue(process.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<List<ProfileRepository>>(){});
    }
}
```

**ProfileRepository.java:**

```
package com.slaweklida.githubDataScrapper;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class ProfileRepository {
    private String repositoryName;
    private String ownerLogin;
}
```

I would like to see the same JSON in browser as in PowerShell.

Comment: You need to read the error stream of `process` and see what's wrong.

Comment: @tgdavies 
`InputStream error = process.getErrorStream();`
`for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) System.out.println(error.read());`
There is nothing in Inteliij console.

Comment: Do yourself a big favour and use `ProcessBuilder` with `inheritIO` (that method at least to begin with) - it will make things a lot easier for you